# Speed up INSERT of 1 million+ rows into Postgres via R using COPY?

Tags: r, postgresql, insert, copy, postgresql-performance

I would like to bulk-INSERT/UPSERT a moderately large amount of rows to a postgreSQL database using R. In order to do so I am preparing a multi-row INSERT string using R.

```
 query <- sprintf("BEGIN;
                         CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
                         md_updates(ts_key varchar, meta_data hstore) ON COMMIT DROP;

                         INSERT INTO md_updates(ts_key, meta_data) VALUES %s;
                         LOCK TABLE %s.meta_data_unlocalized IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

                         UPDATE %s.meta_data_unlocalized
                         SET meta_data = md_updates.meta_data
                         FROM md_updates
                         WHERE md_updates.ts_key = %s.meta_data_unlocalized.ts_key;
                         COMMIT;", md_values, schema, schema, schema, schema)

DBI::dbGetQuery(con,query)
```

The entire function can be found [here](https://github.com/mbannert/timeseriesdb/blob/master/R/updateMetaInformation.R). Surprisingly (at leat to me) I learned that the UPDATE part is not the problem. I left it out and ran a the query again and it wasn't much faster. INSERT a million+ records seems to be the issue here.

I did some research and found quite some information:

[bulk inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres)

[bulk inserts II](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52517/best-way-to-populate-a-new-column-in-a-large-table/52531#52531)

[what causes large inserts to slow down](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114856/what-causes-large-insert-to-slow-down-and-disk-usage-to-explode/114926#114926)

answers from @Erwin Brandstetter and @Craig Ringer were particularly helpful. I was able to speed things up quite a bit by dropping indices and following a few other suggestions.

However, I struggled to implement another suggestion which sounded promising: `COPY`. The problem is I can't get it done from within R.

The following works for me:

```
sql <- sprintf('CREATE TABLE 
            md_updates(ts_key varchar, meta_data hstore);
            COPY md_updates FROM STDIN;')


 dbGetQuery(sandbox,"COPY md_updates FROM 'test.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV;")
```

But I can't get it done without reading from a extra .csv file. So my questions are:

- Is `COPY` really a promising approach here (over the multi-row INSERT I got?
- Is there a way to use `COPY` from within R without writing data to a file. Data does fit in memory and since it's already in mem why write to disk?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5 on OS X and 9.5 on RHEL respectively.

Comment: does it have to be in R? Can R call `psql`? If so, use `\COPY` (not `COPY`)

Comment: @Neil McGuigan yup, gotta be R. R can make any kind of system calls, so psql is an option but since this is part of a package and deployed to wherever I don't want to rely on psql. Still looking for an inside R solution.

Comment: please make Erwin back from Eric - it looks weird

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24289817/5315974 ?..

Comment: Sorry, edited the name. Gotta blame auto correct. Plus me of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RPostgreSQL has a "CopyInDataframe" function that looks like it should do what you want:

```
install.packages("RPostgreSQL")
library(RPostgreSQL)
con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), user="...", password="...", dbname="...", host="...")
dbSendQuery(con, "copy foo from stdin")
postgresqlCopyInDataframe(con, df)
```

Where table `foo` has the same columns as dataframe `df`

Comment: thanks +1 this actually works. I been using the `RPostgreSQL` package for years but didn't search for such a function. It does exactly what I want. Will run a couple of benchmarks to see whether it really speeds things up.

Comment: thanks for your help. It's actually 6 times faster for larger `INSERT`s.

Comment: This link seems to be very helpful too to append more records on the postgres table - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634713/rpostgresql-import-dataframe-into-a-table